# ReactJS: How can I pass a string to use as a function name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, styled-components

I'm building a menu with React. How can I pass a string to a component to use it as a function name?

What's working:

```
<Link to={ROOM({ roomId })}>home</Link>
```

I'm refactoring the components now. I have a component MobileMenu with the Link defined as:

```
  <MobileMenuLink service={'ROOM'} />
```

In a second component I've defined the `MobileMenuLink` as:

```
const MobileMenuLink = ({ style, className, roomId, service }) => {
  return (
    <Base style={style} className={className}>
      <MenuLink>
        <Link to={service({ roomId })}>home</Link>
      </MenuLink>
    </Base>
  )
}
```

How is this possible?

Comment: See the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html) on passing functions, it's a really important concept in React.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't pass a string, pass the `ROOM` function to `MobileMenuLink`:

```
<MobileMenuLink service={ROOM} />
```

And call `service` as you do now, because it's a function:

```
<Link to={service({ roomId })}>home</Link>
```